# Putting controls on a game like tetris on java using JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Ok so we made a game that function like a tetris, so I got how to drop a block on a JTable (we used JTable as the board)and now I need to put the controls for the game and I do not know how to do it. How can I move the blocks to the left or to the right? And where should I put it?

Here is the code

```
public class TetrisTable extends JFrame {


    JFrame frame;
    TestPane pane = new TestPane();
    char ch; 
    public TetrisTable() {
    pane.setTimer();
    }

public void start() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            }

            frame = new JFrame("WORD OF TETRIS");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.add(pane);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private JTable table;
    private TetrisTabelModel model;
    private int currentRow = 0;
    private int currentColumn = 0;
    private int blockHeight = 1;
    private int blockWidth = 0;

    public TestPane() {
        model = new TetrisTabelModel();
        table = new JTable(model);
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Integer.class, new TetrisTabelCellRenderer());
        table.setRowHeight(48);
        Enumeration<TableColumn> columns = table.getColumnModel().getColumns();
        while (columns.hasMoreElements()) {
            TableColumn column = columns.nextElement();
            column.setPreferredWidth(48);
            column.setMinWidth(48);
            column.setMaxWidth(48);
            column.setWidth(48);
        }

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(table);

    }

    public void setTimer() {
        Timer timer = new Timer(1500, new ActionListener() {      //dropper
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                int col = (model.getColumnCount() - blockWidth) / 2;
                int row = currentRow - blockHeight;
                if (row + blockHeight >= model.getRowCount()) {
                    ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                } else {
                    drawShape(row, col, ' ');
                    currentRow++;
                    row = currentRow - blockHeight;
                    drawShape(row, col, ch);
                    System.out.println(ch);
                }

            }
             public void drawShape(int row, int col, char color) {     //naggawa ng shape

                for (int index = 0; index < blockHeight; index++) {

                    if (row >= 0 && row < model.getRowCount()) {

                        switch (index) {
                            case 0:
                            case 1:
                                model.setValueAt(color, row, col);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                model.setValueAt(color, row, col);
                                model.setValueAt(color, row, col + 1);
                                model.setValueAt(color, row, col + 2);
                                break;
                        }

                    }
                    row++;

                }
            }
        });
            timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.setCoalesce(true);
            timer.start();
    }



    public class TetrisTabelModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private char[][] values;

    public TetrisTabelModel() {
        values = new char[10][5];
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return values.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return values[0].length;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return Integer.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return values[rowIndex][columnIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        values[rowIndex][columnIndex] = (char) aValue;
        fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
    }
}
}
 public class TetrisTabelCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {     // naguupdate ng table //

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, "", false, false, row, column);
        setOpaque(true);
        /*
        if (value != null) {
            if (value == 0) {
                setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            } else if (value == 1) {
                setBackground(Color.RED);
            } else if (value == 2) {
                setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            } else if (value == 3) {
                setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            } else if (value == 4) {
                setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            }
            */
        if (value != null) {
            if ((char)value == ch) {
                setText(value.toString());
                setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            }
            else if ((char)value == ' ') {
                setText(value.toString());
                setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            }
        }
         else {
            setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        }
        return this;
    }
}

public void setRand(char ch) {
            this.ch = ch;
        }

    public char getRand() {
            return ch;
        }
```

}`

Here is the GUI (main)

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;        
import java.awt.event.*; 
import java.util.Random;

public class Input_GUI extends JFrame 
{

private Label lbl1; 
private Label lbl2; 
private TextField tf1;
private TextField tf2;
private TextField tf3;
private TextField tf4;
private TextField tf5;  
private Button btn;   

public Input_GUI ()
{
    super ("Input_GUI");
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS)); /* PARA UMAYOS POSITION NG TEXTFIELD */

    /* YUNG LABELS */
    lbl1 = new Label("Welcome to Word of Tetris");
    add(lbl1);
    lbl2 = new Label("Input 5 words (5 letter words only):");
    add(lbl2);

    /* YUNG 5 TEXTBOXES */
    tf1 = new TextField("",10); add(tf1);
    tf2 = new TextField("",10); add(tf2);
    tf3 = new TextField("",10); add(tf3);
    tf4 = new TextField("",10); add(tf4);
    tf5 = new TextField("",10); add(tf5);


    btn = new Button ("Play"); /* BUTTON PARA SA PLAYLISTENER SA PINAKABABA */
    add(btn);
    btn.addActionListener(new PlayListener());

    setTitle("Word Of Tetris");  
    setSize(200, 250);                
    setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );      
    setVisible(true);  
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
}

/* PARA PALABASIN YUNG FRAME */
public static void main(String[] args)
{      
  Input_GUI inpt = new Input_GUI();
} 

/* PAPALABASIN YUNG BOARD AT ILALAGAY SA TEMP VARIABLE YUNG CHARACTERS NG 5 STRINGS WITH RANDOM */
private class PlayListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            TetrisTable gb = new TetrisTable();
            String stf1,stf2, stf3, stf4, stf5;
            stf1 = tf1.getText(); System.out.printf("tf1 = %s\n",stf1);
            stf2 = tf2.getText(); System.out.printf("tf2 = %s\n",stf2);
            stf3 = tf3.getText(); System.out.printf("tf3 = %s\n",stf3);
            stf4 = tf4.getText(); System.out.printf("tf4 = %s\n",stf4);
            stf5 = tf5.getText(); System.out.printf("tf5 = %s\n",stf5);

            /* CONVERTION OF STRING TO CHARACTER */
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String tempstring = sb.append(stf1).append(stf2).append(stf3).append(stf4).append(stf5).toString();
            char[] characters = tempstring.toCharArray();

            /*PARA SA PAGPAPALABAS NG LETTERS, KAYA 47, KASI TINAKE COUNT KO NA KAPAG 46 NA YUNG NAKA
                PILE UP NA TILES SA BOARD, WHICH IS GAMEOVER NA */
            Random random = new Random();
            int index = random.nextInt(25);

                    gb.setRand(characters[index]);
                    System.out.println(gb.getRand());
                    gb.start();


        }
}

}
```

Comment: Did you make any attempts to search for this topic?  What search terms did you use?

Answer (score 0):

A JFrame uses a `BorderLayout`.

So I would guess you would add the tetris board to the CENTER of the frame.

Then for the controls you can add the panel containing the controls to the "LINE_START", "LINE_END", "PAGE_START" or "PAGE_END" depending on how you want the frame to look like.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more information and working examples.

Also, don't use Label, TextField, etc. in a Swing application. Those are AWT components. Instead you should be using `JLabel`, `JTextField`, etc when using Swing.